# How can i share file with virtualbox?

Tags: file-sharing, shared-folders, sharing

I want to simply send a picture and other files to a virtual box and after reading a lot from this platform I still cant find my way through it.

How would one do this in the most simple way possible?

Comment: Really you should say which VBox version, which host operating system, which guest operating system.... there's a bad shortage of crystal balls around ;-).

Comment: im using it on linux ubuntu 15.10 and im running android 0S on it

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest way is probably to enable `Drag'n'Drop` between Guest & Host, but since you wrote neither about your Host OS nor about your Guest OS you might face some Problems. (Also the Virtual Box Version is unknown.)

Nevertheless you can enable `Drag'n'Drop` in the VM Settings:

[image]

You can choose between:

- Disabled
- Host to Guest
- Guest to Host
- Bidirectional

Version is `5.0.2`. The feature was introduced in `4.2`. Facing problems this topic might help. Regardless of your OS there are additional information as well: [Bidirectional drag'n drop is not working with VirtualBox and ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575056/bidirectional-dragn-drop-is-not-working-with-virtualbox-and-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thank you very much. im running and Android OS on the VirtualBox on Ubuntu 15.10. So in this case, will the Android OS be the Host or Guest OS?? Or vice versa with the ubuntu?

Comment: Probably an exotic combination but the hardware which is virtualized - in your case Android - is always the guest. (The guest can't be played alone.) However its not sure if drag&drop works in combination with android, you probably have to try it. I am not versed into Android and VirtualBox in combination

Comment: Alright. thank you very much. i will try that. Please can i add another question? Whats the best way to run Android Apps on ubuntu?

Comment: There is none probably, just for testing apps you can use android studio, but vmware or vbox is probably faster

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not give enough details about your virtualbox I can give only a general solution.

There are two simple ways:

1) use dropbox or any other similar programs - this is maybe not the optimal, but the easiest

2) set up a shared drive, depending on the OS on the virtualbox this can differ, but there is a pretty detailed guide here: http://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine/

Hope it helps...

Comment: Sorry about that I'm running Android OS on it. and my operating system is ubuntu 15.10

Comment: @BrainyBamfo Android is Linux, so you should use mount -t vboxsf NAME /mnt/folder from the guide. Or maybe /mnt/hgfs/folder will be the path, not sure...