# How to share an existing folder from guest Ubuntu Server /var/www/mysite.com/html/ with host Windows 10 running VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: shared-folders

I have a host Windows 10 running Ubuntu Server 18 as a guest via VirtualBox6.1.
How can I share the existing guest Ubuntu directory /var/www/mysite.com/html/ with the host Windows 10?
The plan is that I develop in Windows 10 PHPStorm and Git, but I need to preview my work on a real apache server. The site setup and ability to preview is working perfectly, but now I need to get the share working for the puzzle to be complete.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i share file with virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695713/how-can-i-share-file-with-virtualbox)

Comment: You may add samba server to your Ubuntu and then create a Windows file share. Another idea will be to add the sshd server on Ubuntu if not yet installed and then add a sshFs client to Win10, something like https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you to those that responded, but in the end I found a different solution using sshfs (https://codeyarns.github.io/tech/2018-05-03-how-to-mount-remote-directory-on-windows-using-sshfs-win.html)